# Nokogiri::XML::document canonicalize method returns empty string

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, canonicalization, c14n

I wanted to get a canonicalized version of a piece of xml by using nokogiri, though its canonicalize method is returnin an empty string.

```
d= Nokogiri::XML::Document.new '<a><z></z><b c="d">e</b></a>'
d.canonicalize #=> ""
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? I am using Nokogiri 1.6.7

Comment: I disagree with the way this question was closed. The library is not providing a proper error and the original typo was not the cause for the mentioned problem. The answer matt provided is correct an helpful. Closing this question was abusive moderation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Document::new`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document#new-class_method) doesn’t actually parse the document. You are basically just creating an empty document with a rather odd XML version:

```
d.to_xml
#=> "<?xml version='<a><z></z><b c=\"d\">e</b></a>'?>\n"
```

Instead use [`Document::parse`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document#parse-class_method), or the [`XML()` method on the `Nokogiri` module](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri#XML-class_method):

```
d = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse '<a><z></z><b c="d">e</b></a>'
d.canonicalize #=> "<a><z></z><b c=\"d\">e</b></a>"
```